# For loop error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

```
for t in range(0,12):
    x[t+1,:] = 100 + (0.7 + (0.4/(1 + math.exp(0.1*((x[t,:]- 99)**2)))))
```

I keep getting the error: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.
My x looks as follows:

```
x = np.zeros((13,196))
x[0,:] = 106 * np.ones((1,196))
```

Can someone please help how to get rid of this error?

So a float64 size (13,196), starting with value 106 in the first row.

Comment: At which line do you get the error? What is the value of `t` when you get the error? What is the value of `100 + (0.7 + (0.4/(1 + math.exp(0.1*((x[t,:]- 99)**2))))) ` when you get the error? etc

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The issue is in x[t,:] where you are trying to apply operations to the entire row. You need to specify what you want to do exactly so that we can help you

Comment: The error is at the x[t+1,:] = 100 + (0.7 + (0.4/(1 + math.exp(0.1*((x[t,:]- 99)**2))))) line. How can I see what the value of t is when I get the error? @Dan

Comment: If you keep on trying to drill down where your actual error occurs, you'll find it is here `math.exp(0.1*((x[t,:]- 99)**2))`. Try replacing `math.exp` with `np.exp`. I recommend when you hit errors like this, break down you long single line expressions into simpler multiline expressions. This will help you identify where the error is.

Comment: I want to forecast data. I have a 'zero' point, which has value 106. I want to forecast the next 12 steps that the x has, by using simulations. So I want new values for T+1, T+2, ..., T+12. I have to obtain these forecast by using previous values from x (that's why t+1 and t). Is that a bit more clear?

Comment: _The error is at the x[t+1,:] = 100 + (0.7 + (0.4/(1 + math.exp(0.1*((x[t,:]- 99)**2))))) line. How can I see what the value of t is when I get the error?_ in an interactive python session, just `print(t)` after the error.

Comment: @Ja123 but why do you need the same value for all 196 elements per row, it seems pretty wasteful when you could do it on a single value and get the same numbers out.

Comment: @Dan that's true, how can I change that easily? The np.exp trick worked!! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got TypeError because you pass an array instead of passing a single value in the *math.exp* function. This function exacutable for single values. You can use *np.exp* instead of *math.exp*.